# Unitary matrices that have no effect on symmetric matrices?

Tags: matrices

Let $U$ be an $n \times n$ unitary matrix and $X$ an $n \times n$ real symmetric matrix. Suppose that $$U^\dagger X U = X$$ for all real symmetric $X$, then what are the allowed unitaries $U$? It seems that the only  possible $U$ is some phase multiple of the identity $U=aI$ where $|a|=1$ but I'm not able to show that this is the only allowed unitary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hunch is correct.

Orthogonal projections are self-adjoint and real.  In particular, if $\{e_{1},\dots,e_{n}\}$ is any orthonormal basis, then the operators $\{T_{1},T_{2},\dots,T_{n}\}$ defined by
$$T_{j}(x) = \langle e_{j}, x \rangle e_{j}$$
are orthogonal projections and real.  (If you prefer matrix terminology, then $T_{j} = e_{j} e_{j}^{t}$.)

Observe that $T_{j}U(e_{j}) = UT_{j}(e_{j}) = U(e_{j})$ by hypothesis.  Thus, by definition of $T_{j}$, we see that $U(e_{j})$ is in the span of $\{e_{j}\}$.  In particular, there is a $a_{j} \in S^{1}$ such that $U(e_{j}) = a_{j} e_{j}$.  Moreover, $T_{k}U(e_{j}) = 0$ if $k \neq j$ since $e_{k} \perp e_{j}$.  Thus, in matrix form with respect to the basis $\{e_{1},e_{2},\dots,e_{n}\}$, we obtain 
$$U = \left(\begin{array}{c c c c} a_{1} & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & a_{2} & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & a_{4} \end{array} \right).$$

Next, define $T_{kj}$ for $k\neq j$ by 
$$T_{kj}(x) = \langle e_{j}, x \rangle e_{k} + \langle e_{k}, x \rangle e_{j}.$$
(Matrix terms: $T_{kj} = e_{j} e_{k}^{t} + e_{k} e_{j}^{t}$.)  $T_{kj}$ is the sum of a matrix and its adjoint so it's self-adjoint.  Moreover, both summands are real so $T_{kj}$ is real.  Now
$$T_{kj}U(e_{j}) = a_{j} T_{kj}(e_{j}) = a_{j} e_{k}$$
and $$UT_{kj}(e_{j}) = U(e_{k}) = a_{k} e_{k}$$
so $UT_{kj} = T_{kj} U$ implies $a_{j} = a_{k}$.  Do this for each choice of $j,k \in \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ to find $U = a I$, where $a = a_{1} = a_{2} = \dots = a_{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Show that $U$ must be diagonal by considering $X=e_i e_i^T$.

Then show that $X e_k$ (if non zero) is an eigenvector of $U$ 
corresponding to the eigenvalue $[U]_{kk}$ for any $X$ symmetric
and conclude that $\ker (U-[U]_{kk}I)$ is the entire space.